# Error when both ZfcRbac and ZendDeveloperTools enabled

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Here is my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "0.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "0.1.*",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-rbac": "~2.4"
}
```

When I have both ZfcRbac and ZendDeveloperTools enabled, I will have

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService'
```

If I disable ZfcRbac, I can see the development bar. If I disable the ZendDeveloperTools, I can see my homepage.

What did I do wrong here?

Thanks,

ttk

Comment: As you're using ZfcRbac with ZfcUser ave you added the authentication service alias to your app config? .. as detailed here -> https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/07.%20Cookbook.md#using-zfcrbac-and-zfcuser

Comment: That does not help and with other error message. And it does not make sense if I disable ZendDeveloperTools, I can see my homepage.

Comment: What's the other error message?

Comment: My bad.

After Crisp's comments. The error message was:
'No role provider has been set for ZfcRbac'.

So, I have to start setting the ZfcRbac right away. Crisp's comment helped.

Thanks for both.

Comment: could you please post your configurations for Zenddevelopertools with ZfcRbac.